# Execute the method after previous method finishes

Tags: java, android, multithreading, arraylist

I am making an android app in which I am fetching data from internet and storing it in a ArrayList with custom adapter. Fetching data takes time and in that time next function runs on its own. I only want the next function to run when data is completely fetched. What can I do? I think it has to do something with threads kindly explain what threads are and how can we use them?

Let's say there are 2 functions

Function A
Function B

I only want the function B to run when function A has completed its task. is there anyway to do that?

Comment: Can you post the code for both the functions and their calls?

Comment: `A(); B();` should work. Otherwise you're going to need to provide more info about how and why your functions break the laws of time.

Comment: Sounds like you want a callback.

Comment: If you want to learn multithreading then its ok but if you want to get your work done then please don't reinvent the wheel. you should prefer `Volley` or `Retrofit` libs for  network requests. it will give you Success or Failure methods for http request. On Success you could call other method

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of resources available online where you can obtain information on Threads in Java.

I highly recommend the official [Java Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html).

[This Introduction](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2077138/java-concurrency/introduction-to-java-threads.html) isn't half bad either.

As for obtaining information in one method and then waiting until it is done to run the next, as @cHao said, just call the methods sequentially like this

```
A();
B();
```

Unless you already have multiple threads set up in your code, this should work just fine.